# Break a string into chunks, keeping words whole in Python

Tags: python

I'd like to break a long string (say, 500 characters) into smaller chunks (say, <=100 characters each), but keeping words whole. That is, the chunks should be as close to 100 characters as possible, but should not cut off whole words. My first reaction was to split the string and loop through each word, concatenating each word to a buffer until reaching the limit, and then starting over for each chunk, but I figure there must be a more efficient way.

Thanks!

Comment: <=100 or as close to 100 as possible? Which one is it? Or both? Is 101 ever permissible?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, it's <=100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the `textwrap` module in python:

```
s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu,"

import textwrap
var = textwrap.wrap(s, 100)
for line in var:
    print(len(line))

print(var)
```

You can learn [more about it here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html).

[Live Demo](http://pythonfiddle.com/textwrapping-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
import textwrap

long_string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu,'
string_list = textwrap.wrap(long_string,100, drop_whitespace = False)

for line in string_list:
    print(line)

print(string_list)
```

output:

```
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean ', 'massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec ', 'quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. ', 'Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, ', 'imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. ', 'Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, ', 'porttitor eu,']
```

use drop_whitespace = False to keep the original spacing

Check out the other options [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.wrap)

Answer (score 0):

Without additional imports, try:

```
s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu,"

out = []; leftover = ""
for i in map(''.join, zip(*[iter(s)]*100)):
    i = leftover+i
    toappend, _ , leftover = i.rpartition(" ")
    if len(toappend) > 100:
        leftover = toappend[99:]
        toappend = toappend[:99]
    out.append(toappend)

print out
```

[out]:

> ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
>   commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean', 'massa. Cum sociis natoque
>   penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
>   Donec', 'quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
>   sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Don', 'ecpede justo, fringilla
>   vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut,
>   imperdiet', 'a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede
>   mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras', 'dapibus. Vivamus elementum
>   semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula,
>   portti']